# Is there a way to continue my script after running an if statement to catch anomaly in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have tried searching online but I can't seem to find anything that would answer this question.

I current have a script that is running, and I am using an if statement to catch anomaly.

```
if test <= limit:
    return True
```

This works as intended, but I am looking to reduce said code into a single line like

```
return True if test <= limit else [continue with script]
```

But I have no idea what to put in the [continue with script] part.

Comment: Where are you using that snippet? please post the complete code.

Comment: Why would you want to do that when you have clear compact working code? (missing a colon)

Comment: Just curious what would the else be in this case. I mean aren't you curious?

Comment: There is not easy construct, because the ternary operator only makes sense to use when you want to `return` something in either context! You've probably need a really ugly construct like `try: return True if False else int('a');except ValueError: pass `, which is much worse than your original design

Comment: Yeah, I have thought of something similar too but it seemed counter-intuitive and made the code harder to understand. Was wondering if there is any function that would function something like break in a loop.

Comment: Well, you can in fact simply remove the line break to write it on one line. But why? Do you suffer an acute shortage of lines?

Comment: No, I was just curious what would the else be in this case. If there is such a function, I would want to know it.

Comment: If you write `return <expression>`, then it's always going to return and you can only adjust the value. That's not what you want. You want to only execute the `return` statement *if* and only *`if`* some condition is true; for which `if` is the right thing to use. – There may be even more pythonic solutions for your case overall (e.g. involving exceptions), but we can't tell you without more context.

Comment: Throwing exceptions sounds like way more trouble than it is worth for a basic if statement. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm basically saying that perhaps you can leverage exceptions which would be triggered at some point to terminate your function in case of that "anomaly" instead of writing an explicit check for it; but again, I'm just spitballing here…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do that, at least in principle, although it's not really a single line of code. At all. And it's almost certainly not what you want:

```
class LimitException(Exception):
    pass

def LimitExceptionRaiser(msg):
    raise LimitException(msg)

def f(test, limit):
    try:
        return True if test < limit else LimitExceptionRaiser("Must continue")
    except LimitException:
        pass
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f(1, 2)) # -> True
    print(f(2, 1)) # -> False
```

Is this solution pretty? Will the next guy who has to maintain your code praise you? Seems unlikely.

Whatever follows `else` must be a value, so I can't simply put `raise Exception()` there, but have to trick the interpreter into thinking that it gets a value, namely, the return value of some other function `LimitExceptionRaiser`. But this function doesn't return a value, it stops the current line of execution and yanks you forcefully out of it.

Once again,

```
def f(test, limit):
    if test < limit:
        return True
    return False
```

seems like a much saner solution (to clarify, I assume that you do some additional computation inside the function, otherwise, you could simple do `return test < limit`).

Comment: I tried to satisfy the curiosity of @GoodbyeWorld if such a construction is possible at all (since he/she expressed a theoretical interest), while making clear why one shouldn't use it. It would be nice if the downvote would be accompanied with a comment.